# Angular directive won't remove html added to element

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that is added to other elements which is used to inject html as a popover.  When any of the buttons in the popover that are added are clicked, the directive should remove the popover from the dom.

The problem I'm having is that the call to .remove() on the popover element is not removing that element from the DOM.  Other code, calling the same method to remove said popover works.  It just doesn't work when the popover itself makes that call.

The directive:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('my.module')
        .directive('assetActionPopover', ['$compile', '$timeout', function ($compile, $timeout) {
            return {
                scope: {
                    editAction: '&',
                    copyAction: '&',
                    deleteAction: '&',
                    createPresentationAction: '&'
                },
                restrict: 'A',
                transclude: false,
                compile: function compile(element) {
                    element.attr('ng-click', 'showPop()');

                    element.removeAttr('asset-action-popover');
                    element.removeAttr('data-asset-action-popover');

                    return{
                        post: function postLink(scope, element) {
                            $compile(element)(scope);
                            scope.showPop = function () {
                                if (angular.element('.pop').length === 0) {  //this is the popover's style, there should only be one at any time
                                    // <nav class="pop"><ul> see showPopover()
                                    scope.showPopCover();
                                    scope.showPopover();
                                }
                            };

                            var template = '<nav class="pop"><ul>' +
                                '<li ng-click="editAction(); removeMe();"><span class="icon edit"></span>Edit</li>' +
                                '<li ng-click="deleteAction()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove ng-click="deleteAction()"></span>Delete</li>' +
                                '<li ng-click="copyAction()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span>Copy</li>' +
                                '<li ng-click="createPresentationAction()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span>Create Presentation</li>' +
                                '</nav>';

                            //adds a background element to the body tag that covers
                            //an area and sets itself up for a click handler to then remove itself
                            scope.showPopCover = function () {
                                var popCover = angular.element('<div class="pop-cover" ng-click="removePopCover()"></div>');
                                var popCoverEl = $compile(popCover)(scope);
                                angular.element(document.body).append(popCoverEl);
                            };

                            //shows the popover in the same general area of the DOM element that
                            //that this directive is attached to
                            scope.showPopover = function () {

                                var popEl = $compile(template)(scope);
                                //apply a class that can be used in css to determine things at run time (like visibility)
                                //and append to the element that we are attached to
                                element.addClass('pop-parent-show').append(popEl);
                            };

                            //this works to remove both the "cover" div and the menu created by the temaplate
                            scope.removePopCover = function () {
                                angular.element('.pop-cover').remove();
                                angular.element('.pop').remove()
                                element.removeClass('pop-parent-show');
                            };

                            //this does not work
                            scope.removeMe = function () {
                                angular.element('.pop').remove();
                            };
                        }
                    };
                }
            };
        }]);
})();
```

Usage:

```
<article asset-action-popover editAction="foo()" copyAction="bar()" deleteAction="bam()"></article>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Getting any errors?  Are you adding jquery before angular so you can use selectors?  Any reason you're not storing the element in a function variable instead of using selectors?  Have you tried adding console.log statements to show that removeMe is actually being called and what angular.element('.pop') returns?

Comment: is `editAction()` working? A fail there may mean skipping the next function call. Try passing single function to ng-click and wrapping the other 2 in the scope with it

Comment: @JasonGoemaat yes to pretty much everything you asked.  I can see that the function is getting called.  There are no errors, and angular.element('.pop') returns the element expected...  Tried storing the element as a variable, but the same result is reached either way.  Super frustrating, and thanks for your input!

Comment: @charlietfl editAction is working.  Single method call produces the same affect (when just using removeMe)

Comment: So the ".pop" element is visible, in the console does the statement remove it?

Comment: @JasonGoemaat inspecting the DOM show that the element is still there after the call.  Using the console to run jQuery('.pop').remove() DOES however remove the element.

Comment: @JasonGoemaat attached is the console output

Comment: It is visible, and the statement does not remove it.

Comment: what happens when you run angular.element(".pop").remove() from the console?